Need to run sudo sysctl -p after each reboot after updating to 24.10
After updating to 24.10 I need to run sudo sysctl -p for the changes in /etc/sysctl.conf to be applied. After I reboot, my custom config file called /etc/sysctl.d/99-enable-ipv4-forwading.conf is not loaded:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1

Once I run sudo sysctl -p the changes are loaded and my wireguard reverse VPN works again. After reboot gone. This worked until 24.04.
Does anyone know what has been changed here and how to fix it? Thanks!

What is the name of your custom config file? Did you edit the /etc/sysctl.conf itself?

The name of the file is /etc/sysctl.d/99-enable-ipv4-forwading.conf and the content as described in the question

I am not able to repro this on my machine https://imgur.com/a/57iz8pD . I can redirect you to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+filebug to file a bug and I can help you more there.

Strange behavior on a standard package like sysctl, I've had same problem, as a workaround I added sysctl --system in /etc/rc.local , I'm sure that ubuntu team will solve this.
